# Can't find the mode for multiple common values

Tags: pandas, statistics

I want to find the mode in a large dataset. When I have multiple common values I still want to know what they are instead I get output such as:

```
'no unique mode; found %d equally common values' % len(table)

StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 24 equally common values
```

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics 

df=pd.read_csv('Area(1).txt',delimiter='\t')
df4=df.iloc[0:528,5]
print(df4)

statistics.mode(df4)
```

But given that the dataset is quite big with many common values, I get the StatisticsError I mentioned earlier. Since **statistics.mode** is not giving me the required output, I have also tried **statistics.multimode()** but for some reason this command does not work/isn't recognizable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use `mode` from `pandas`

```
df4.mode()
```

Comment: Thank you. This works!
And do you know why statistics.mode() or statisttics.multimode() did not work?

Comment: @Kurapika no sure about your data , that function should work

Comment: multimode was introduced in Python 3.8, you probably have an older version.